# Не получается корректно создать sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется такая задача.
Таблица `Students` имеет поля `StudentId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Group` и содержит информацию о студентах института. Таблица `Exams` имеет поля `StudentId`, `ExamName`, `Result` и содержит результаты экзаменов студентов.

- a) написать SQL запрос, который выводит имена и фамилии студентов у которых больше двух экзаменов с результатом меньше 3.
- b) написать SQL запрос, который выводит название групп, в которых таких студентов больше 10

На пункт a) ответил:

```
SELECT Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, COUNT(Student.StudentId) as count 
FROM Student INNER JOIN Exams 
ON Student.StudentId = Exams.StudentId
WHERE Exams.Result < 3
GROUP BY Student.StudentId HAVING count >= 2;
```

нужен пункт b)

Comment: приучитесь перечислять в group by все поля которые не агрегаты. это только mysql позволяет такие вольности, и то, регулируется настройками

Comment: в чем проблема со вторым запросом? джойн тот же, группирвка уже по группе. считать число различных студентов, или нет?

Comment: да, нужно определить, если больше 10 в группе, то вывести название этой группы.
Именно по синтаксису не могу найти как правильно записать.

Comment: `having count(distinct student_id) >= 10` не найти, или что?

Comment: в задании второй запрос строится на выборке первого, я не могу найти как эту вложенность правильно записать:

Comment: `select ... from ( подзапрос ) as t`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Так что там с вариантом b, можетк показать что получилось?

Comment: Да, пожалуйста покажите, только учусь работать с БД, не совсем понимаю, как это сделать, задача подобная

Answer (score 0):

Я решил вот так:

a)

```
SELECT Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, COUNT(Student.StudentId) as count 
FROM Student INNER JOIN Exams 
ON Student.StudentId = Exams.StudentId
WHERE Exams.Result < 3
GROUP BY Student.StudentId HAVING count >= 2;
```

---

b)

```
SELECT student._group, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
  SELECT Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, Student.StudentId, COUNT(*) as count 
  FROM Student INNER JOIN Exams 
  ON Student.StudentId = Exams.StudentId
  WHERE Exams.Result < 3
  GROUP BY Student.StudentId HAVING count >= 2) AS fail
JOIN Student ON fail.StudentId = Student.StudentId 
JOIN Exams ON Student.StudentId = Exams.StudentId 
GROUP BY Student.StudentId 
HAVING  count > 10;
```